# Autofilter for multiple not equal values

Tags: vba, excel

I am adding autofilter for excel table as follows.

```
With Sheets("Sheet1")
With .ListObjects("Summary").Range
    .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=">400000", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:=Array("<>440400", "<>440600", "<>440300")
    .AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:=">110", Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria1:="<105"
    .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
End With
End With
```

n the result I am geeting value greater than 400000 . But I am getting 440400,440600 and 440300 values also in the result. How Can I add both filters?

Comment: You can only include a total of TWO not equals in a criterium. To do more you will need to instead utilize the AdvancedFilter of the Range object.

Comment: AvancedFiltered is a STD function in xls, Tab Data, Avanced. you can use the excel Help or see http://www.onlinepclearning.com/vba-advanced-filter-multiple-criteria/

Answer (score 1):

So far, as I know, it cannot be done.

My work around :

1) Highlight records that meet criteria, loop one by one

2) Then Filter by Higlight

Hope this help !

Answer (score 0):

I know this doesn't meet your exact specifications (I wasn't sure of the precedence order, so I just made it up), but this should work:

Add a field to your table as a formula, something similar to:

```
=if(OR(AND(Field1>=400000,Field1<>440400,Field1<>440600,Field1<>440300),
   AND(Field5<110,Field5>105))
```

Again, I totally made that up based on values you had, so I realize it's not consistent, nor do the actual field names match.

Then, have your vba code filter on this new column/field.