# How to use <> array criteria

Tags: excel, vba

let me ask my problem, i'm just a beginner in vba. 
I have to filter a column with criteria

```
<>array ("0402", "0603", "0805", "1206").
```

i have tried this one but not work for me :

```
Rows (1).AutoFilter Field:=9, Criteria1:=Array("=<>0402", =<>0603", "=<>0805", "=<>1206"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

For information, value in column field 9 is paste value of right text function. So what i have to define the character? is it text or numeric? and how about the array?

Comment: There is a quote missing in `Array("=<>0402", =<>0603", …` it must be `Array("=<>0402", "=<>0603", …`. Please also note that *"not work for me"* is a completely useless error description, always tell which error you get and in which line.

Answer (score 0):

you can use only two not equal to criteria's. Refer the below post for more clarity

[Autofilter for multiple not equal values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33686240/autofilter-for-multiple-not-equal-values)

Answer (score 0):

Public Sub REName_()

```
    Dim d1() As Variant: d1 = Array("0402", "0603", "0805", "1206")

    Dim r As Range: Set r = Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion

    r.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=d1, Operator:=xlFilterValues

End Sub
```