# AdvancedFitler Out Values from ListRange using Formula

Tags: excel, vba, advanced-filter

I'm trying to setup AdvancedFilter to filter out a ListRange of items. After some testing, I realized that it only accepts using a "formula" of `<>A` when I use a criteria range of 2 cells. If I add a third `<>B` it just does nothing.

My original thought was simple to prepend to my column `<>` to each cells value, but now it seems that won't work. I need to figure out a way to have both a formula and a range somehow applied.

IE:

Data:

```
Let Num
A   1
B   2
C   3
```

This Works for Filter Range:

```
Let
<>B
```

This Doesn't:

```
Let
<>B
<>C
```

But my CriteriaRng looks like this:

```
Let
B
C
```

How I can reference a way to say for all items in `Let` column, Filter `<>Cell.Value` in `CriteriaRange:=`

Here's the basic code I tried/debugged this issue with:

```
 FilterRng.AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterInPlace, CriteriaRange:=Range("D1:D3"), Unique:=False
 Stop
 FilterRng.AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterInPlace, CriteriaRange:=Range("D1:D2"), Unique:=False
 Stop
```

Updates:

I found this example --> https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/with-adavnced-filter-how-do-i-exclude-a-value.733153/page-2

```
=ISNA(MATCH($A9,Exclude!$A$1:$A$2,0))
```

But I'd need to built that formula via VBA and make it much more generic. I'm better w/ VBA then formula's.

I also read in this post that he basically uses highlighting via regular filter, then another filter based on highlighting, but I know there is a better way utilizing a formula in a cell.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/34012365/5079799

I think I also somewhere you can do "or" operations when staggering rows w/ advanced filter, so I could make my column a staggered column, but that also sounds hacky and I couldn't get it to work on my brief attempt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I basically copied my answer from this one, but built the `FormulaStr` and automated it more, as thats the point of VBA!

https://stackoverflow.com/a/28506854/5079799

```
Sub Test()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ActiveSheet

Dim CriteriaRng As Range, DataRng As Range
Set CriteriaRng = ws.Range("D1:D3")
Set DataRng = ws.Range("A1:B4")

Dim FormulaRng As Range, FormulaStr As String, DataRngCellTwoStr As Range
Set DataRngCellTwoStr = Cells(DataRng.Row + 1, DataRng.Column)
Set FormulaRng = ws.Range(Cells(2, CriteriaRng.Column + 1), Cells(2, CriteriaRng.Column + 1))
FormulaStr = "=ISNA(MATCH(" & DataRngCellTwoStr.Address(False, False) & "," & CriteriaRng.Address & ",0))"
FormulaRng.Value = FormulaStr
ws.Range(Cells(1, CriteriaRng.Column + 1), Cells(1, CriteriaRng.Column + 1)).Clear
Set FormulaRng = ws.Range(Cells(1, CriteriaRng.Column + 1), Cells(2, CriteriaRng.Column + 1))

DataRng.AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterInPlace, CriteriaRange:=FormulaRng, Unique:=False

End Sub
```

Notes:

- You must enter Formula on 2nd row and make FilterRng exactly 2 rows!
- The Header Should be BLANK
- Formula should looks like this `=ISNA(MATCH(A2,$D$1:$D$3,0))` with A2 being first row below headers of criteria column in filter range and D1:D3 being the criteria column.

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple lines in your Criteria you're doing an OR operation. If you want to do an AND operation you need a single line in your criteria but the same Caption listed multiple times, see below.
[image]

If you name your ranges: Database, Criteria, and Extract respectively then record a macro and run the advanced filter it will write the code for you. You can then modify the code to accept variable input.

Comment: Yes, I've read about that, but I strictly use VBA solutions, great answer tho